# Spritekit Joystick

Tags: objective-c, animation, sprite-kit

I'm trying to execute some animations of my player sprite whenever I change the direction of the joystick.

I'm using [TheSneakyNarwhal's drop in Joystick class](https://github.com/TheSneakyNarwhal/SpriteKit-Joystick/wiki) which uses the following methods:

```
 if (joystick.velocity.x > 0)
    {
        [self walkRightAnim];
    }
    else if (joystick.x < 0)
    {
        [self walkLeftAnim];
    }
    if (joystick.velocity.y > 0)
    {
        [self walkUpAnim];
    }
    else if (joystick.velocity.y < 0)
    {
        [self walkDownAnim];
    }
    if (joystick.velocity.x == 0 && joystick.velocity.y == 0)
    {
        [self idleAnim];
    }

My [self walkRightAnim];

    - (void)walkRightAnim {

        NSLog(@"%f", self.joystick.velocity.x);

        SKTexture *run0 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"right1.png"];
        SKTexture *run1 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"right2.png"];
        SKTexture *run2 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"right3.png"];
        SKAction *spin = [SKAction animateWithTextures:@[run0,run1,run2] timePerFrame:0.2 resize:YES restore:YES];
        SKAction *runForever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:run];
        [self.player runAction:runForever];
    }
```

However, whenever the velocity.x of the joystick is above 0 (moving right) it keeps calling the method from the beginning and won't actually play the full animation.

Only when I stop using the joystick does it play the whole animation.

Comment: Why is "comparing equality" for analog joysticks not enough? You are not providing sufficient information on what the problem is.

Comment: I have changed the explanation hope this makes more sense i am still new in sprite kit and Xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you keep calling your animation over and over again. This would prevent the animation from actually playing past the first couple of frames.

Create a BOOL which you would set the first time the animation runs. Subsequent calls to the animation would check the BOOL's status and determine if the animation is already running. You can reset the BOOL once the joystick is no longer pointing right.

---

Create a BOOL property:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL animationRunning;
```

When your joystick values indicate you want your player to run right you call the animation method:

```
[self runRightAnimation];
```

Before the animation is run, the BOOL is checked to see if it is already running:

```
-(void)runRightAnimation {

    if(animationRunning == NO) {

        animationRunning = YES;

        // your animation code...
    }
}
```

Remember to set your `animationRunning = NO;` and stop the animation when the joystick is no longer in the desired position.

Comment: will it be possible for you to show me an example with the code i have provided, is would be so much appreciated. I tried but i think im still doing it wrong :(

Comment: Awesome its working now thanks you so much. I see what i did wrong now i did not add the @property (nonatomic) BOOL... thank you so much for your expert advice